# Find a number given a property of two of its factors.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Q. If all the (positive) factors of $n$ are arranged in ascending order, then the product of the $10^{\text{th}}$ and the $23^{\text{rd}}$ factor is $n$. Find $n$.

P.S I have never encountered something like this, so I couldn't find an approach to use the data given. The only things which I could think of is:

(i) No. of factors of $n > 23$.

(ii) $n > 230$ as $10^{\text{th}} \text{ factor} > 10$ and $23^{\text{rd}} \text{ factor} > 23$.
Beyond this, I can't think of as how to proceed.

Also I am hoping for a rigorous method - if the answer is given by hit and trial or found by software, then prove it is the only possible $n$.

Comment: Wouldn’t any $n=p^{31}$, where $p$ is a prime satisfy this.

Comment: How many factors will $n$ have?

Comment: Well, you can take $n=p^{9+22},$ where $p$ is prime, and then the $k$th factor of $n$ is $p^{k-1}.$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the divisors are, in ascending order
$$d_1=1,d_2, \ldots, d_{10},\ldots, d_{23},\ldots, d_m=n $$
then we always have $n=d_k\cdot d_{m+1-k}$. We conclude that $m=32$. And vice versa, if $n$ has $32$ divisors, then $n$ is a solution to our problem.

If $n=2^a3^b5^c\cdots$, then the number $m$ (also know as $\tau(n)$) equals $(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)\cdots$. We conclude that any $n$ of the form $n=p^{31}$ works ($p$ prime), as well as $n=p_1^{15}p_2$ or $n=p_1^{7}p_2p_3$, $n=p_1^7p_2^3$, $n=p_1^3p_2p_3p_4$, $n=p_1^3p_2^3p_3$, $n=p_1p_2p_3p_4p_5$, where the $p_i$ are any pairwise distinct primes.

Comment: I haven't hear of that result $n = d_k d_{m+1-k}$. Could you briefly tell me how that is shown/proved or point me to a link?